# Proof: Antiderivative of a function differ by a constant

Tags: calculus

> Let $f(x)$ a function defined at $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and assume that $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ are the antiderivatives of $f(x)$ in $I$, so there is a $c$ such that for all $x\in I$, $F(x)=G(x)+c$

Let  us define $H(X)=F(x)-G(X)$ therefore $H'(X)=F'(x)-G'(X)=f(x)-f(x)=0$.
Which theorem should be used to finalize the proof?

Comment: Mean ValueTheorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need that $I$ is an interval, I assume this is intended. If not it is just not true. (Abstractly, you want the domain to be connected.)

Then use the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem).

If $H$ is non-constant there are $a,b$ such that  $H(a) \neq H(b)$, so by MVT you get a contradiction to $H'$ identically $0$.

Comment: Just to be sure I fully grasped the contradiction, if we have $H(a)\neq H(b)$ by MVT there is $c$ such that $H'(c)\neq 0$ in contradiction ?

Comment: Yes. Because there is a $c$ such that $H'(c) = (H(b)-H(a))/(b-a)$ and the latter is not $0$

Answer (score 4):

This is only true if $I$ is an *interval*.

Let $x_1,x_2\in I$, with $x_1<x_2$; then there is $\xi\in(x_1,x_2)$ with
$$
D(x_1)-D(x_2)=(x_2-x_1)D'(\xi)
$$
where $D(x)=F(x)-G(x)$. This is the mean value theorem applied to $[x_1,x_2]\subseteq I$.

Since $D'(\xi)=F'(\xi)-G'(\xi)=0$, …

---

More generally, if a differentiable function defined over an interval has zero derivative, then the function is constant.

The standard counterexample is
$$
f(x)=\arctan x+\arctan\frac{1}{x}
$$
defined on $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$. It has everywhere zero derivative, but it is not constant.

Comment: Why is this function a counterexample? Because it have 2 constant values?

Comment: @gbox Yes, it is not constant on the whole domain.

Comment: at the point x=0?