# Show that two primitives/ antiderivatives are related via a constant

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $I \subset R$ be an interval. A differentiable function $F: I \rightarrow R$ is called a
>   primitive for the function $f : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ if
>    $$F'
> (x) = f(x)$$ for all $x \in I$.
>
> **Show:** If $F_ 1$ and $F_2$ are two primitives for $f$ on $I$ then there is a constant
>   $C \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $F_2 \equiv F_1 + C$, i.e. $F_2(x) = F_1(x) + C$ for all $x \in I$.

What we have covered so far is the formal definition of the derivative in terms of the limit:
$$ \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{F_1(x+h)-F_1(x)}{h}= f(x)$$
$$ \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{F_2(x+h)-F_2(x)}{h}= f(x)$$

I do not see how I can **prove** firsthand that these two functions differ by a constant. I know it to be true from my pre-calculus and calculus experience, but how would one make the argument from an analysis point of view, can someone give me a hint as to where this constant 'appears'.

---

We normally just define $F_2=F_1 +C$ and then it would follow immediately that these two functions have the same derivative.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862231/proof-antiderivative-of-a-function-differ-by-a-constant

Comment: It is essential that the domain is an intervall.

Comment: AH, the glorious $MVT$, cool!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: What is the derivative of $F_1-F_2$?

Comment: Zero of course, so we can define a new function $H(x)=F_2 -F_1$  such that $H'(x) =0$

Comment: And then apply the MVT to the interval.

Comment: @WesleyStrik I think you're thinking too complicated. If $H'(x)=0$, then $H(x)=C$ for some constant $C$. What does this say about  the relationship between $F_1$ and $F_2$?

Comment: It means the function $F_1 - F_2$ is constant, see my proof below using the MVT.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If $F_1,F_2$ are primitives of $f$, by linearity of differentiation,

$$(F_1(x)-F_2(x))'=F'_1(x)-F'_2(x)=f(x)-f(x)=0.$$

Remains to prove that the antiderivative of $0$ is a constant function.

Answer (score 0):

Let $G(x)= F_1 - F_2.$

We observe that $G'(x)=0$. We claim this means that $G(x)$ is constant.

Suppose  on the contrary the function is non-constant this means there must exist $a, b \in I$ and where  $a<b$ such that $G(a) \neq G(b)$.

We consider $[a,b]$. Now We apply the mean value theorem to this interval and the function $G(x)$. We get that there must exist a $c$ such that:
Which is a contradiction.
$$G'(c)= \frac{G(b)-G(a)}{b-a}  \land G'(c)=0,$$
$$ \frac{G(b)-G(a)}{b-a}=0 \implies G(a)=G(b). $$
We conclude that $G(x)$ is constant. Thus, $F_2$ and $F_1$ differ by a constant $\square$.